# Nginx dynamic vhost returns ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Tags: regex, nginx, vhosts

I'm trying to setup the server to use a single conf file to serve all the development sites.
So my /ect/nginx/site-available/dev.example.com looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ~^(?<folder>[^.]*).(?<user>[^.]*).dev.example.com;

    charset utf-8;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;



    root /var/www/projects/dev/$user/$folder/htdocs;
    access_log /var/www/projects/dev/$user/$folder/access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/projects/dev/commons/logs/htdocs/error.log;

    location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|css)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           30d;
        add_header Pragma "public";
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV $user;
            include fastcgi_params;
   }


    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The regexp are working correctly and if I run http://energy.magana.dev.emaple.com with an index.php with phpinfo() the file is working and it seems that everything is ok... but if i run wordpress I get ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT.

If I change the file /ect/nginx/site-available/dev.example.com without the regex and setting up the absolute paths everything works.

What I'am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the variable SERVER_NAME that was interpreted as `~^(?<folder>[^.]*).(?<user>[^.]*).dev.example.com` to fix this overriding the variable works

```
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $folder.$user.dev.example.com;
```